# FireBase Recycler Adapter doesn't retrieve data from FireBase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

My database looks like this
[image]

I'm trying to fetch all this data from that USER ID inside Cart. But my `RecyclerView` shows nothing. After checking, the `adapter.getItemCount()` returns 0. Where did I wrong? This is my code :

**onStart()**

```
private void loadData(){
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        userID = auth.getUid();
        final DatabaseReference cartList = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Cart");
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Cart> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Cart>()
                .setQuery(cartList.child(userID),Cart.class).build();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Cart,CartHolder> adapter
                = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Cart, CartHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CartHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Cart model) {
                holder.txtGia.setText(model.getTotal());
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public CartHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cart_item,parent,false);
                CartHolder holder = new CartHolder(view);
                return holder;
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();
    }
```

**Model**

```
    public class Cart {
        public String pID,num,time,addr,total,userID;
        public Cart(){}
    
        public Cart(String num,String pID,String time,String addr,String total,String userID) {
            this.num = num;
            this.pID = pID;
            this.time = time;
            this.addr = addr;
            this.total = total;
            this.userID = userID;
        }
    
        public String getNum() {
            return num;
        }
    
        public String getpID() {
            return pID;
        }
    
        public String getTime() {
            return time;
        }
    
        public String getAddr() {
            return addr;
        }
    
        public String getTotal() {
            return total;
        }
    
        public String getUserID() {
            return userID;
        }
    }
```

and **ViewHolder**

```
public class CartHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public ImageView shibaImg;
    public TextView txtTen,txtMota,txtGia,txtThoigian;
    ItemClickListener listener;

    public CartHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        shibaImg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_img);
        txtTen = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_ten);
        txtMota = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_mota);
        txtGia = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_gia);
        txtThoigian = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_history);

    }
    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        listener.onClick(v, getAdapterPosition(),false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is my query wrong?

Comment: hey, did you enable proguard rules?

Comment: Yes, I did! So strange that I use this for another table in Firebase and it works but not for this one.

Comment: hey, and have you added this in your proguard rules: `-keep class your.app.package.model.**{*;}`

Comment: I had and still not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code seems to be the problem:

```
cartList.orderByChild("userID").equalTo(userID)
```

This code takes every child nodes directly under `cartList` and orders them on their `userID` property. But there is no `userID` property in your screenshot, so this results in an empty list.

My best guess is that the **key** of each node under `cartList` is the user ID, in which case you can instead use:

```
cartList.child(userID)
```

So:

```
final DatabaseReference cartList = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Cart");
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Cart> options =
        new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Cart>()
        .setQuery(cartList.child(userID),Cart.class).build();
```

Comment: I tried but my `RecyclerView` still has nothing, the `adapter` size is 0 sir.

Comment: That's unexpected. Can you edit your question to show the updated code?

Comment: I tried to add `userID` to the table and `orderByChild(userID)` but forgot to update. Sorry sir

Answer (score 0):

I've finally figured it out.
For some reason, `RecyclerView` on my `CartActivity` needs time to load data in (Maybe cause I have 3 `RecyclerView` on  `HomeActivity` and sometimes data show up and sometimes It don't, usually 1 or 2 / 3 RecyclerViews show data). When I reload (press back and Start Activity again), RecyclerView will appear and show data.